# mobile j2me map viewer library

Tags: java-me, mobile, gis

Is there any open source gis library for mobile devices to work on J2ME? I need to create simple gis application on mobile device and to be apple to retrieve and enter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If GPL license is acceptable for You, then take a look at [Mapping library from Nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/lib-application-samples)